# triple integral bounded by cylinder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the triple integral [image]
where E is the solid bounded by the cylinder [image] and the planes 
 [image] and [image]
in the first octant.

I tried really hard to get the write answer but I am still struggling in the picture so I could not find the limits

Answer (score 1):

you can check if this is correct:
$$\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\int_{r=0}^3\int_{x=0}^{\frac{rcos\theta}{3}}r^2sin\theta dxdrd\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

We have a cylinder with a circular cross-section of radius 3 oriented with its symmetry axis on the $ \ x-$ axis (which points off to the left in the graph above).  The volume is bounded by the $ \  xy - \ \text{and} \ \ yz-$ planes and the oblique plane $ \ y = 3x \ $ , so it is a narrow wedge or "sliver" in the first octant.

[image]

The projection of this volume onto the $ \ yz-$ plane is a quarter-cicle, so it is about equally convenient to integrate using either Cartesian or cylindrical coordinates.  In the former, since we have the "thickness" of the wedge extending in the positive $ \ x-$ direction, we can write

$$ \  \int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt{9 - y^2}} \int_0^{y/3}  \ \ dx \ dz \ dy \ \ = \ \ \int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt{9 - y^2}} \ x \ \vert_0^{y/3}  \ \  dz \ dy  $$

$$ = \ \ \frac{1}{3} \ \int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt{9 - y^2}} \ y   \ \  dz \ dy \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{3} \ \int_0^3 \ yz \ \vert_0^{\sqrt{9 - y^2}}   \ \   dy \ \ = \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{3} \ \int_0^3 \ y \ \sqrt{9 - y^2}  \ \   dy \ \ . $$

Making the substitution $ \ u \ = \ 9 - y^2 \ , \ du \ = \ - 2y \ dy \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ dy \ = \ -\frac{1}{2} du \  $ , we obtain

$$  \rightarrow \ \ \frac{1}{3} \ \int_9^0 \  \sqrt{u}  \ \  \left( -\frac{1}{2} du  \right) \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{6} \ \cdot \ \frac{2}{3} u^{3/2} \ \vert_0^9  \ \ = \ \frac{1}{9}  \cdot \  9^{3/2} \ = \ \frac{27}{9} \ = \ 3 \ \ . $$

In cylindrical coordinates, we would write the axial coordinate as $ \ x = \frac{1}{3} y = \frac{1}{3} r \cos \theta \ $ . The integral is then as shown (with one typo) by **ketan**, which produces

$$  \int_0^{\pi / 2} \int_0^3 \int_0^{(r \cos \theta)/ 3} \ \ dx \ \ r \ dr \ \ d \theta \ \ = \ \  \int_0^{\pi / 2} \int_0^3 \ \frac{1}{3}   r \cos \theta \ \  r \ dr \ \ d \theta $$

$$ = \ \  \frac{1}{3}  \ \int_0^{\pi / 2} \int_0^3 \   r^2 \cos \theta  \ \ dr \ d \theta \ \ = \ \  \frac{1}{3}  \ \int_0^{\pi / 2}  \   \frac{1}{3} r^3 \cos \theta \ \vert_{r=0}^{r=3} \ \  d \theta $$

$$ = \ \  \frac{1}{9}  \ \int_0^{\pi / 2} \  3^3 \ \cos \theta \  \ \  d \theta \ \ = \ \  3  \  \sin \theta \ \vert_0^{\pi / 2} \ = \ 3 \ (1 - 0 ) \ = \ 3 \ \ .  $$

We can compare this volume to that of a hemispherical "sliver" of radius 3 , which will be slightly smaller.  The "opening angle" of the wedge is given by $ \ \tan \phi \ = \ \frac{1}{3} \ \Rightarrow \ \phi \ \approx \ 18.4º $ , so the wedge's volume is

$$ \ \frac{18.4º}{360º} \ \cdot \ \frac{2 \pi}{3} \ \cdot \ 3^3 \ \approx \ \frac{1}{20} \ \cdot \ \frac{2 \pi}{3} \ \cdot \ 27 \ = \ \frac{54 \pi}{60} \  \approx \ 2.83 \ \ .  $$

So our result appears to be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

colormegone is almost right. They just forgot the z integrand.

$\int _0^3\int _0^{sqrt\left(9-y^2\right)}\int _0^{\frac{y}{3}}\:zdxdzdy$

$\int _0^{\frac{y}{3}}\:zdx = \frac{zy}{3} $

$\int _0^{sqrt\left(9-y^2\right)}\frac{zy}{3}dz = \frac{y\left(9-y^2\right)}{6}$

$\frac{1}{6}\int _0^3\:9y-y^3dy = 1/6(\frac{81}{2}-\frac{3^4}{2})$ about 3.375